# How do I prevent my click handler from being set twice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, onclick, click

I'm using JQuery 1.12.  For some reason a click handler is getting set twice, even though I'm unbinding the click before setting it again ...

```
  $styledSelect.unbind('click')
  console.log("setting click")
  $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
    console.log("opened");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
  });
```

but yet when I click my menu to open it, you see the "opened" statement printed out twice.  See my fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/6fjnnu55/1/ .  Does anyone know how I can properly set my click handler so that I don't set it twice?

Comment: HOw is this a duplicate?  THat answer recommends adding "this.unbind("click")", which is already the first line in the code snippet I posted.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. @Dave: add `console.log(e)` into your click handler - and see that it actually handles different events. The last one is 'natural' (user-triggered), all the other are generated by the script itself.

Comment: Yes, it's not a dupe of that, but based *solely* on this question and not using the external jsFiddle which contains pages and pages of code that nobody should be expected to read through, it looks that way. You need to learn how to make a [mcve].

Comment: I have reported myself to site administrators and have been sentenced to 15 lashings and 5 years hard labor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be on lines 35-36:

```
    }).focus(function() {
  $(this).find('.select-styled').click()
```

It seems "on focus" you click the select widget... I'm guessing you either do not want to click on focus *all the time* or maybe not even at all...

**UPDATE**

So looking at the event as suggested I think will not really help, because you need to distinguish cases where you have one event from those where both are fired... I'd use a flag variable for this, see my updated fiddle, in particular lines 30, 39 and 75

http://jsfiddle.net/6fjnnu55/3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Exactly. The reason is that `click` native event is fired after `focus` one - unless the element has already been in focus.

Comment: Hi @MacPrawn, thanks for identying this.  Indeed, I only want the "click" function invoked when the focus function is called because someone clicked the "Tab" key to reach the element (as opposed to clicking on it with the house).  How can I distinguish the two?

Comment: You may either delay that, or just check the event itself within the handler. There're several distinctions for the triggered events (isTriggered flag set among the most prominent )).

Comment: When I try and see the value for "e.isTriggered", I get the error, "TypeError: e.isTriggered is not a function"

Comment: @Dave Don't add `()` after `e.isTriggered`, it's just a property.

Comment: Thanks, although calling "e.isTriggered" still produces "undefined" for either event.  I think MacPrawn's solution with flags is probably the only answer here.

Comment: I don't know if you saw, but I edited my answer, with a link to a new fiddle for you...